# Apps that exhibit bugs will be rejected

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad and iPhone running iOS 9 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.

Specifically, when we attempted to add a second account, an error was displayed.

Please see the attached screenshot(s) for additional information.
Apple team doesn't mention the bugs discovered. What should i do.
They have mention the bug related to twitter login.[image: Screen Shot given by apple]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: You can ask questions to an Apple reviewer in intunesconnect to have more information.

Comment: From where can i ask in resolution center the have said 
Submit an appeal to the App Review Board

Comment: It can be about programming if there will be bug in twitter api in ios 9 or any other issue we can discuss about it.

Comment: You haven't given enough information. Have you asked Apple the steps they took to reproduce the bug. You need to show relevant code.